# Java Regex matching word

Tags: java, regex, string, search

I have a file im reading through and searching for words.

name = jake

active Doppler name = 200ms

while searching im using

```
if(line.contains("name")
```

this statement finds both line but I only need it to find the first line because I have a separate statement to fine the "active Doppler name". So I need help with the regex to check that its just whitespace before the word "name". these are a few options I have come up with but don't work

```
if(line.contains("\\s+\bname")
```

or

```
if(line.contains("^\\s+name")
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.contains` does not take a regular expression as argument.

You can use:

```
// matches the whole line:
//            ┌ start of input
//            | ┌ any or no whitespace (as your original pattern suggests)
//            | |  ┌ literal "name"
//            | |  |   ┌ any other character sequence to follow, or no characters
line.matches("^\\s*name.*");
```

**Note**

If you want to improve on this, you can declare a constant `Pattern`, and match / back-reference every line.

For instance:

```
// similar as before, but captures the value for "name" 
// and validates with "=characters" after it
static final Pattern NAME_VALUE = Pattern.compile("^\\s*name\\s*=\\s*(.+)");
// ...
Matcher m = NAME_VALUE.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    // "jake"
    String myValue = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: @Nate you're welcome. Be sure to check my edit, that might come in handy.

Answer (score -1):

If "name" always is the first word in your line you can match with /^ *(name)/